# javascript onload in while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to initialize inputs with maps api autocomplete -the number of inputs comes from database- , but I'm not able to execute a simple javascript function in a while loop.

The initialazing is working fine with `window.onload`, but I can't execute the function in this while loop...

No errors appearing in Console, 1 result is coming from database.

```
$limit = $bdd->prepare('MySQL query');
$limit->execute();

 while ($city = $limit->fetch()) { 
       echo 'result'; ?>

       <script type="text/javascript">
              function initializeLimitCity() {
                      alert("Hello World");
              };
              initializeLimitCity();
      </script>

<?php
}
```

Comment: Why are you throwing a lot of `<script>` bits? Put all the code in one big `<script></script>`section, and execute from the window.onload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant declare same function more times... Change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initializeLimitCity() {
    alert("Hello World");
  };
</script>

<?
$limit = $bdd->prepare('MySQL query');
$limit->execute();

while ($city = $limit->fetch()) { 
  echo 'result'; ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     initializeLimitCity();
  </script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
              function initializeLimitCity() {
                      alert("Hello World");
              };

      </script>
<?php
$limit = $bdd->prepare('MySQL query');
$limit->execute();

 while ($city = $limit->fetch()) { 
       echo 'result'; ?>

       <script type="text/javascript">
              initializeLimitCity();
      </script>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the function with the same name several times, it won't work.

I'd not generate it this way. Let the client (Javascript) do the work, resulting in less bytes to transfer (HTML):

```
<?php
$cities = $limit->fetch_all();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initializeLimitCity(cities) {
        alert(cities);
    };
    initializeLimitCity(<?php echo json_encode($cities); ?>);
</script>
```